# Check if a strings has special characters except hyphen?

Tags: php

How do I check if a strings has special characters except hyphen?

Example:

```
$str1 = "what?"; 
has_special_characters_except_hyphen($str1); // should return true

$str2 = "whats-up"; 
has_special_characters_except_hyphen($str2); // should return false

function has_special_characters_except_hyphen($str) {
     // check for special characters except hyphen
}
```

Comment: To be able to define such a function you first would have to define what you actually consider a "special character" and what not. Why do you think some characters are "special"? They are all characters, none of them are somehow "special".

Comment: The typical motivation for the always returning questions of this type point towards an issue with what you want to do with the treated strings. Typically this is about code not being as robust as it should be... Wouldn't it make more sense to solve the actual cause of the issue instead of trying to cure the symptom as you apparently try to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option uses `preg_match` with the pattern `[^A-Za-z0-9-]`:

```
$str1 = "what?";
if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/", $str1)) {
    echo "YES";
}
```

This would print `YES` should there be at least one character in `$str1` which is not alphanumeric or hyphen.

Comment: You can add underscore as valid character I think in the regexp

Comment: @Shim-Sao It isn't completely clear I guess what is being whitelisted here and what is being blacklisted.  My answer is my best guess lacking any other information.

Comment: I know, more informations are needed., this kind of methods are often use to clear path it's why _ can be correct (for me).